# Give an example of a space that contains a unit interval and a dense set of non-isolated degenerate points

Tags: general-topology, cantor-set

Let $X$ be a compact metric space.
Let $X^{deg} = \{x \in X: \{x\}$ is a connected component$\}$.
A space $X$ is said to be **almost totally disconnected** if the set $X^{deg}$ is dense in $X$.
A point $x \in X$ is called **isolated** if and there exists a neighborhood of $x$ which does not contain any other points of $X$.

Give an example of an almost totally disconnected compact metric space that has no isolated points and contains only one connected component that is not a singleton - a unit interval.

My idea: Consider a unit square. Take unit interval over the number $0$ on $x$-axis. Take the classic $1/3$ Cantor set over the number $1$. Take Cantor sets over $1/2$ such that instead of middle third we remove middle ninth ($3^2$th), over $1/3$ such that we remove middle $3^3$th and so on.

I'm not sure if this works and I struggle to prove the desired properties.

Comment: What is meant by "degenerate"?

Comment: that they are degenerate (singleton) connected components

Comment: Never heard of non-isolated points. Couldn't for instance $[0,1]$ fit your requirements? It contains $\mathbb{Q}\cap [0,1]$ which is a dense set...

Comment: I think I was not specific enough, will rewrite the question a bit. Sorry.

Comment: You're on the right track. See my A.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $C(1)$ be the Cantor set. For $1<n\in \Bbb Z^+$ let $C(n)$ be a "fat Cantor set" with Lebesgue measure $1-1/n.$ Each  $C(n)$ is an uncountable closed nowhere-dense subspace of $[0,1]$ with no isolated points.

Let $X=A\cup B$ where $A=[0,1]\times \{0\}$ and $B=\cup_{n\in\Bbb Z^+}(C(n)\times  \{1/n\}).$